# Memory usage requiring parts of JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

Let say that there is a file `mod.js` that contains a lot of functions and variables, most of them being exported using `module.exports`.

If I want to use only one of these exported functions, between these options:

```
const mod = require("./mod");
mod.function();
```

or

```
const {function} = require("./mod");
function();
```

is there a sensitive difference in the memory usage? Does node remove the unreferenced elements inside `mod.js` to save memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading a module loads all the code in the module into server memory. It does not know what code may or may not be called and does not remove any code that isn't used.

Typically, the memory usage by code on a server is inconsequential (server-side memory, code only loaded once). If you want to not have code loaded that you don't use, then you need to refactor your modules so that you can only load code that is actually needed.  This is one of the points of node modules. Load the ones you need, don't load the ones you don't need.  Design the modules to be useful packets of code to load together.

> is there a sensitive difference in the memory usage?

Not usually for servers, unless you had a gigantic module.  Modules generally shouldn't be large enough that they would make a big dent in server-side memory just from loading their code.  If they were, then they should probably be broken up into much smaller pieces that can be loaded as needed.

> Does node remove the unreferenced elements inside mod.js to save memory?

No, it does not.

Comment: I agree with the quote `refactor your modules so that you can only load code that is actually needed`, but this sounds unrealistic to me. Some examples: loadash, a crypto library where you only need a few things, etc...

Comment: @lilezek - Well, you're asking for a feature that node.js does not have.  I'm describing to you how it works and what your options are.   If a particular third party module was really a problem in this way, then you can either find some other solution that isn't too much of a pig, copy just the desired code out of the module into your own module, etc...  These are your choices.  Unless you're in a memory constrained server environment (like on a Raspberry Pi or something), then are you sure you really have an issue with code taking too much memory on your server?